# How to display seconds using TimeSpan on Timer Tick Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using below code to display time left in `hh:mm:ss` format for example if duration is `30min`, it will show like this `00:30:00` and after 1 min it will show `00:29:00`, how can i also display the remaining seconds and decrease them accordingly.,

**Edit**

I tried `timer1.Interval = 1000;` and
`examTime = examTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`

But its not showing me seconds reducing each second, How do i do it ?

```
        public SubjectExamStart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             examTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(conf[1]));
                    label1.Text = examTime.ToString();
                    timer1.Interval = 60 * 1000;
                    timer1.Start();
         }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == timer1)
            {
                if (examTime.TotalMinutes > 0)
                {
                    examTime = examTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                    label1.Text = examTime.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Exam Time is Finished");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Subtracting `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` you need to subtract from `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`

```
        public SubjectExamStart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             examTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(conf[1]));
                    label1.Text = examTime.ToString();
                    timer1.Interval = 1000;
                    timer1.Start();
         }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == timer1)
            {
                if (examTime.TotalMinutes > 0)
                {
                    examTime = examTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    label1.Text = examTime.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Exam Time is Finished");
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to format the Time Span value while assigning to Label... You can use below..

```
label1.Text = examTime.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this properly, you will need to keep a track of when the timer was started

```
DateTime examStartTime;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer runTimer;
TimeSpan totalExamTime = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0); // Set exam time to 1 hour 30 minutes.

if (runTimer == null)
    runTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
runTimer.Interval = 200;
runTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(runTimerTick);
runTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(runTimerTick);
examStartTime = DateTime.Now;
runTimer.Start();
```

Then in the event handler you can do:

```
public void runTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan currentExamTime = DateTime.Now - examStartTime;
    if (currentExamTime > totalExamTime)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exam Time is Finished");
        runTimer.Stop();
        runTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(runTimerTick);
        runTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can u please explain why `interval=200` ? Can you please edit this according to my code ,because I am fetching time from database

Comment: I have update the answer for your example. Please accept this as the answer if it helps you...

Comment: `TimeSpan totalExamTime = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0);` this line I can't set time exactly since in my database I have stored time as `120,60 ,30 ` these 3 values as minutes so how do i write this line now `examTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(conf[1]));`

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this will work for u

> set timer interval=1000

```
minremain=1200000; //Should be in milisecond
timerplurg.satrt();

 private void timerplurg_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      minremain = minremain - 1000; //substring One second from total time
            string Sec = string.Empty;
            if (minremain <= 0)
            {
                lblpurgingTimer.Text = "";
                timerplurg.Stop();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
        var timeSpan =   TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(minremain));

                var seconds = timeSpan.Seconds;
                 if (seconds.ToString().Length.Equals(1))
                {
                    Sec = "0" + seconds.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Sec = seconds.ToString();
                }

                string Totaltime = "Remaing Second: " + Sec;
                lblpurgingTimer.Text = Totaltime;
            }
```